# Is it possible for some messagebus subscriblers to handle message in UI thread, some others in background thread?

Tags: reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI's `RegisterScheduler` like this:

`MessageBus.Current.RegisterScheduler<string>(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler, someContract);`

I want some of the message subscribers (who register this message) handle it in UI thread, but at the same time, some other subscribers handle it in backgroud thread.

Here is the use case: Some of the message's subscribers will handle UI related data which must happen in UI thread. But I want to reduce the UI thread usage as minimum as possible, so I would like to have other operations (not related to UI) happen in background thread. Is it possible for ReactiveUI?

My current solution is to use 2 different contract string, which in fact can be considered 2 different messages. It works, but both messages should be send out together, which makes me feel reduntent.

Any ideas?

Fei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps ignore the scheduler, or set maybe set your default appropriately (the default is `CurrentThreadScheduler`) and just use `ObserveOn` to define which scheduler the handler will be executed with when you need to.

To handle on the UI thread:

```
MessageBus.Current.Listen<string>()
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Subscribe(message => { /* ... */ });
```

To handle on a thread pool thread:

```
 MessageBus.Current.Listen<string>()
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
    .Subscribe(message => { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: exactly what I want.